# How to re size a flash file in a banner rotator code?

Tags: html, flash, image, tags, resize

In the part of the code I would like to change the size of this to 468 x 60

```
param value="clickTAG=http://www.hotel-lefortovo.ru&externalImage=http://adv.citycatalogue.ru/banners/634157464649540000.swf" name="FlashVars"
```

I know it is possible with :

```
embed src="http://adv.citycatalogue.ru/banners/634157464649540000.swf" quality="high"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="468"
height="60"
```

But is it possible to do it in a param?
Edit : format code

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to set the size of an embedded SWF in a param. Params are used to send information to Flash. It is up to the HTML to set the size of the SWF being embedded, and it must do this in the embed (or object) tag.

Also, you are using a really old link in your embed markup. Macromedia doesn't even exist anymore. Sure, that link will still work, but you should use this one instead:  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Adam, Ill keep on working on this then, unless you have a quick solution. The thing is , I have a banner rotator  with two banners.    object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="banner.swf" width="468" height="60" . As you can see here I have set the width and height of the object, but I would also like to set the same attributes for the link I posted at the top. How would I go about doing this? ( any suggestions? , otherwise its ok ill keep googling for it)